# How to navigate in iOS application

Tags: ios, navigation

I have a screen in my application (login), that may be presented from any other screen
i want to put the logic of starting that screen outside of my ViewControllers, so it is not duplicated

is this possible ?

this screen may also be loaded upon an NSNotificationCenter notification message that i received

Answer (score 1):

So, I'd put this into a controller where each of the view controllers calls this controller to perform the login. When the login is requested, pass the requesting view controller (or its parent if it isn't full screen) as a parameter.

Now, when the login view needs to be presented you have a generic way of presenting it from inside the 'login controller'. The requesting view controllers know nothing about the 'login controller' and the 'login controller' knows nothing about the requesting view controllers.

When triggered by a notification the app delegate can get the root view controller from the app window and pass that as the requesting view controller.

Comment: Not right now, maybe in a while. It's a class with a class method basically. I'd also add a block to notify the sender about the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a ViewController for your login screen and give it a "storyboard id" under the "Identity inspector".
And when you'd want to show it you can instantiate it like this:

```
    loginViewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardID"];
```

after that you can either push it if you are using a navigationController or add it as a subview.

**EDIT**: how do i know if it is present:

```
 NSArray *controllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController* controller in controllers)
    {
        if ([controllers isKindOfClass:[LoginController class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"is already present");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if this viewcontroller is already present in the stack ?

Comment: you can use `[self.navigationController popToViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>]`

Comment: how do i know that it is present ?

Comment: Why would it be in the stack? You should only be able to login or cancel and both action pop to remove the login VC...